# Append to the end of derby.database.classpath

Tags: classpath, derby

In Apache Derby, it's possible to add multiple entries to derby.database.classpath using by using a colon separator. Like this:

```
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath', 'APP.StringUtilities:APP.FileUtilities');
```

That works well if you know in advance what things need to be loaded. In my case, a database is shared between a number of applications, each of which can install jar files into it.

I'd like to know if it's possible to append to an existing list, much like in linux you might do a:

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:SomeOtherFile.jar
```

I've tried this:

```
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath', select SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath') || ':APP.FileUtilities' from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
```

And this:

```
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath', values SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_GET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.database.classpath') || ':APP.FileUtilities');
```

But neither worked. Is there any way to append to the existing value of derby.database.classpath?

Comment: `derby.database.classpath` is classified as a dynamic property, which means you should be able to change it and have the changes take effect. However, the changes will only take effect on the next connection to the database, I believe. Are you disconnecting and reconnecting after you change the property?

Comment: Thanks Bryan, the changes take effect right away. Even after a reconnecting, the value is still the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your question is really about how to **get** the current value of the database property, so that you can set a new value that includes the current value plus additional data. Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right :)